# Jenkins master takes a long time to collect results from slave nodes

Tags: jenkins

How can I figure out what Jenkins is doing during that long pause?

- Verbose logging?
- Some debug plugin?
- Log files?
- Do you know which Jenkins source file is responsible for those finishing steps?
- Is it possible to patch Jenkins with a modified class to add some debugging print or log statements?
- Other ideas?

Sample end of console output:

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /opt/jenkins/workspace/job/dir/target/a.jar to com/package/a.jar
channel stopped
>>>> hangs 5-10 min here <<<<
Triggering a new build of ...
Triggering a new build of ...
Triggering a new build of ...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Have you reviewed [Jenkins Logging](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/12561/13379) - see links mentioned there.

Comment: @IanW Thank you for the link, I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Jenkins job is using the Maven plugin, probably you would check out this Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-52150. Either disable disabled automatic fingerprinting in job Maven plugin advanced settings or add `-Dhudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.DISABLE_FORCED_FLUSH=true` option to Jenkins command-line.

Comment: Thanks! Disabling automatic fingerprinting seems to solve the delay at the end.

Comment: Did not work for me on `Jenkins 2.289.2` , I will update alternate answer if I find it.